# Printing of for loop's value outputs nil in Lua

Tags: lua

Take a look at the ***for loop*** and the ***word*** part of it specifically.

```
local words = { 
    "One - Test", 
    "Two - Test", 
    "Three - Test"
}

local find = "Test"

local function getWord(partialName)
    partialName = partialName:lower()
    for _,word in ipairs(words) do

        if string.find(word:lower(),partialName) then
            print(word)
        end
    end
end

getWord(find)
```

```
Output:

One - Test
Two - Test
Three - Test
```

I'm trying to store everything that gets outputted to other variables. ***print(word)*** outputs what you see above, but how can I only get the ***One - Test*** result of it and store it to another variable? I've tried using ***print(word[1])*** to test it out, but it didn't work and outputted nil.

```
nil (x3)  -  Client - Local Script:14
```

Now how can I fix that? Very much appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to get only `One`, or `One - Test`? If `One`, you need to split the string and return the first part, if `One - Test`, you can get it by `words[1]`.

Comment: @pavelsaman Let's say that I have a huge table and used this script to locate "One - Test" using the "find" variable, I would like to store the outputs in order to other variables and "word[1]" doesn't help unfortunately.

Also words[1] is only for when I know where "One - Test" is, but let's say that I didn't.

Comment: You can create a lookup table like so `huge_table = { ["One - Test"]=true, ["Two - Test"]=true }`, then searching for some key would be just `huge_table["One - Test"]`.

Comment: `One - Test` is not a word. You should use more suitable names. Same for `getWord`. A function named getWord should return a single word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of printing your result you can simply put every result in a table.

```
local words = { 
    "One - Test", 
    "Two - Test", 
    "Three - Test"
}
   
local find = "Test"

local function getWord(partialName)
    partialName = partialName:lower()
    local output = {}
    for _,word in ipairs(words) do 
        if string.find(word:lower(),partialName) then
            table.insert(output, word)
        end
    end
    return output
end

print(table.concat(getWord(find), "\n"))
```

Comment: Thank you very much and yes, I will choose more suitable names later on, this was just for testing!